Is the reason for guitar "tone suck", i.e. loss of high end frequencies with impedance mismatching, actually due to high reactance?
When connecting a guitar's output to an input with insufficiently high input impedance, the signal is undesirably filtered, which is referred to as "tone suck". To deal with this, it is common wisdom to always connect an output to an input with much higher impedance than the output, i.e. "impedance bridging".
Is this merely to ensure that the ratio of reactance to resistance is low in the total impedance applied to the voltage source (in this case, the guitar coils), so the relative voltage drop is negligibly dependent on frequency? If so, could it be said that "tone suck" is not really caused by connecting a high impedance output to an insufficiently high input impedance, since if the input also had a low resistance (but high reactance) then the tone suck would still occur?

Relevant extra information (cable type and length tone losses)

Yes, or most likely so.
We can model the pickup like so:

simulate this circuit – Schematic created using CircuitLab
Now, I'm not well versed in guitar pickup design and typical values, but my understanding is the typical design -- a coil, around a magnet and/or pole pieces, which magnetically biases the strings that in turn induce EMF in the coil -- has values of about this, and we aren't too concerned about the mechanical coupling because the coupling factor is small (tiny string over big pickup, tons of air gap), so we can model the small-signal equivalent as the inductance and resistance measured at the terminals, plus a small EMF in series due to the signal itself.
Along with the cable capacitance (its inductance can be ignored at low frequency and high impedance), we have an RLC resonant circuit.
The 1nF equivalent corresponds to, more than a few meters of cable really, so it might be less representative here, but it also reduces to a scaling factor, and qualitatively, these results will be representative.  We can say, as Cc and Rin are varied, a range of response will result, with cutoff determined by component values, whatever they are in practice.
Because it's resonant, we obtain a 2nd order peaked response:

These values give close to critical damping (a bit under, actually), because \$Z_0 = \sqrt{\frac{L}{C}}\$ is 44.7kΩ.  If we chose R1 = Zo, and no Rin (or infinite value), this would give critical damping, but we have a somewhat more complicated situation where loss is distributed both in series and parallel; we don't need 100% damping as either single resistor, and the combination means we need less in series, or more in parallel, to obtain the same damping value.
If we pick other resistances, we get different damping values:

For Rin = R1, we have a maximum power point matching condition, but only when X_L --> 0, i.e. at low frequencies; but we get very little signal at low frequencies anyway because dΦ/dt is small (that is, the transducer gain also needs to be multiplied into this curve as well to get the overall response), so this might not be very useful to us, and in particular for non-bass application, we'll be interested in those higher frequencies or harmonics, and need a better-matched amplifier -- and we can see there's already some dB of roll-off for the 10k case at mid-high frequencies (2-5kHz).  Note that nothing we do has any effect on the HF asymptote: aside from loading it too low (L1 dominates, cutoff frequency falls), this slope is practically fixed by the values of L1 and Cc.
If the observed effect is reduced frequency response at very low loads (a few kohms or less), this seems quite consistent with the simulation.  The most effective solution is shortening the cable -- perhaps even equip the guitar with a preamp in the body (which can improve SNR as well) -- and then matching the impedance appropriately.
We can restore frequency response by simply compensating for it -- cranking up the tone controls -- but this raises the gain for noise in those bands as well, which is to say, we can't make back any SNR.  It's better to use tone controls for only modest compensation -- say give or take 10 maybe 20 dB -- which is usually about all the range such controls span, anyway.

Thanks for the detailed response. Maybe this is hand-wavy, but I thought it would be as simple as: $$V_L = \frac{V_S}{1 + \frac{Z_S}{Z_L}},$$ where $L$ stands for the load and $S$ stands for the source. From there, the impedances can be decomposed into their resistive and reactive components: $$V_L = \frac{V_S}{1 + \frac{R_S + iX_S(\omega)}{R_L + iX_L(\omega)}},$$ where the frequency dependence of the reactances is emphasized. From there, we can see that as the resistive components are made large, the frequency-dependent terms can be ignored.

The transfer function is more complicated than that; in particular, C dominates over all at HF, and raising R (either one) only exacerbates this. The contradiction is that C || RL is not additive, as RL + jXL implies.  Put still another way: RL is a function of ω too (indeed, $Z_L = \frac{R - j\omega C R^2}{1+\omega^2 C^2 R^2}$).

(I don't know why inline TeX is not rendering in my comments.) I hadn't considered the cable capacitance. But would it be true that for $\omega C << R_L$, my reasoning would stand?

[Use backslash dollarsign for inline TeX here.] For the purely inductive case, the circuit reduces to a loop of just R + L, roll-off is single-pole at $\omega_0 = \frac{R}{L}$, for total loop resistance R. The 1k case above in particular, the two real poles are apparent, reducing to the RL case at ~500Hz and RC at ~100kHz.

It could be.
If you have a long cable, it adds more capacitance, i.e. capacitive reactance.
High capacitive reactance means the capacitance shunts current more for high frequencies so impedance is lower for high frequencies and thus amplitude of voltage is lower.
It does not matter where the capacitance is, on the cable or on the amplifier input, it will load down high frequencies from the high impedance pickup output that can't drive the load.
It depends on the source (i.e. pickup) source impedance, how it behaves with capacitive loading. The pickup has inductance and resistance. So capacitance forms an 1st order RC lowpass filter that simply rolls down. But with inductive source impedance the parasitics form an LC filter which is a 2nd order lowpass filter, but depending on source and load reaistances, it also defines how much there will be peaking at LC resonance and what is the width of the resonance.
